# Знак препинания — какой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> *— Возьми сметаны.*
>
> *— А сметана(?) она для чего?*

Подскажите, какой знак здесь может иметь место — тире или запятая? или может двоеточие?

Answer (score 2):

По правилам можно поставить как запятую, так и тире (двоеточие не подходит):
http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=64 — последний абзац с примечанием.

Но при запятой в данном случае есть два варианта интерпретации: нужный и
*А сметана? Она для чего?* || Не подходит по контексту.

При тире лишь один вариант интерпретации — нужный. Так что оно выигрывает.

Примечание: многоточие не ставится просто так, оно выражает раздумье (человек думает, что сказать дальше), ну и соответствующая интонация (не просто пауза); если человек спрашивает уверенно (без раздумий), то многоточие никак не подходит.

Answer (score 2):

Именительный темы — один из типов конструкций с двойным обозначением, или *сегментированных конструкций*, в которых два подлежащих: первое — не­местоименное существительное, второе — местоименное суще­ствительное.

> — Хлеб, он сам растет, а уголь добывать надо... (М. Шолохов, Они
> сражались за родину);
> — Немец, он всегда был жадный до чужой земли (М.
> Бубеннов, Белая бере­за); — Кошки... они приятные,— неуверенно и
> содрогнувшись произнес Илья Игнатьич (Л. Леонов, Дорога на океан).

https://lektsii.org/8-15853.html?ysclid=l7mdiqm8in691427030

Из возможного выбрал бы многоточие:

```
— Возьми сметаны.

— А сметана... она для чего?
```

Comment: Мне не понравилась «одна из конструкций сре­ди многообразной группы конструкций». Спасибо.

Comment: Хорошо,  можно удалиться.